# New window containing opened document not found with getWindowHandles

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I'm testing an application that generates and xml file. I need to verify some parts of the content of this XML file. What I do is open a dossier for the XML file, click on a link to generate the actual XML file and when the popup appears (Open, Save, Cancel) I choose to open the file. The file then opens in a new window but I can't seem to locate this new window. When I try to determine the nr. of windows with:

```
System.out.println("Windows: "+driver.getWindowHandles().size());
```

The answer in the console is: Windows: 1

I can see the window with opened XML file on my screen (document is downloaded to Temporary Internet Files and opened in a new window) but can't interact or even find it with my script.

In short what I do is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath")).click(); //click on a link to the xml file
Thread.sleep(3000); //wait for the Open,Save, Cancel popup 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("D:\\Test\\gros\\OpenDownloadDoc.exe"); //this executable (created with AutoIT) is only to send the keystrokes 'Alt-N' to focus on the Open,Save, Cancel popup and choose Open
Thread.sleep(3000); //wait for the new browser window containing the xml file is opened
System.out.println("Windows: "+driver.getWindowHandles().size());
```

I now have two windows, one with the application where I clicked the link to open the XML file and another window showing the actual XML file.

When I send the following line:

```
 System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
```

It returns the pagetitle for the application (which makes sense as I have not told it to switch to a different window). I just can't seem to find the other window containing the file, let alone switch to it.

Comment: Witch browser are you using? does the file opens in new separate window or as new tab?

Comment: If you are using IE, then look at [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6435)

Comment: I'm using IE10. Window opens as seperate window, not new tab. I'm currently looking into the link Kiril posted. Still trying to figure out how to fix it though...

Comment: Why not directly read the XML file from the place it is saved uisng XmlReader